# Node child_process.spawn() wrapped in a promise- block event loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

From [Node documentation on Synchronous Process Creation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) it states that if I run `child_process.spawnSync()` it will:

> block the Node.js event loop, pausing execution of any additional code until the spawned process exits.

If I used the asynch version `child_process.spawn()` and wrapped it in a promise for synch behavior, would it still block the event loop?

The process I am using `spawn` for only takes a second, but I am using SSE streams and I don't won't it to keep a new user from getting a stream if it's at that split second.

Comment: Wrapping things in promises don't give you sync behavior. It only gives you composability for async behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I used the asynch version child_process.spawn() and wrapped it in a promise for synch behavior, would it still block the event loop?

No. Node core functions that are async cannot be made synchronous. Promises can make your code read more top-to-bottom as if it were synchronous, but the actual mechanics remain asynchronous and non-blocking.